# Can't Setup a Enterprise Certification Authority at Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, pki

I'm trying to install a Enterprise CA with Active Directory Certification Service at my Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise virtual machine, but I can't choose the "Enterprise" setup type.
Why this is happening?

I have uploaded a print screen that show my two virtual machines. The top windows is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, named 2k8R2, running as Domain Controller. You can see that the second machine, named Enterprise, has joined the domain. When I try to install AD DS at the second machine, the "Enterprise" option is unavailable.

http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6045/6296292773_841b14b2f5_b.jpg

Comment: Is the account being used to install the CA part of the Enterprise Admins or Domain Admins group?

Comment: I only saw your question here after I discovered the problem looking at support forums. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
I need to login at ENTERPRISE computer as a domain privileged account, to then install Active Directory Certificate Service with Enterprise setup type. I was login as a local machine privileged account.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but in my case, I just remove Active Directory Certificate Service (Manage -> Remove Role And Features). After that, I installed Active Directory Domain Services. Next step, I reinstalled Active Directory Certificate Service successfully.